# MVC EntityFramework - How to create an SQL IN condition

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to know how can I create an SQL IN using Entity Framework.

I need to retrieve from my database all rows that have the ID equal with a list of IDs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this. It will generate a `IN` clause:

```
var yourIds=new List<int>{1,2,3,4};
var result= db.yourTable.Where (u => yourIds.Contains(u.IdToCompare));
```

Where `db` is the linq context